# When should I use a title in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-alertdialog, human-computer-interface

From a user-interface perspective, why is there a [`title`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) option to an `AlertDialog`?  Why doesn't the [`message`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setMessage%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) alone suffice?  Do we really need a title?  If so, please provide visual examples of where a title would be useful.

The `AlertDialog` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) shows an `AlertDialog` without a title, and it looks perfect to me:

[image: AlertDialog without title]

Comment: I didn't downvote or vote to close, though I think it's the following: *"why is there a title option to an AlertDialog? [..] Do we really need a title?"* is really subjective. Every opinion counts, there is no right answer - this is not a good fit for SO as stated in the FAQ (hence "not constructive" votes). Also the answer you've given just states *what* should be in the title, not *why* the title option exists in the first place. It does not really answer your question.

Comment: @alextsc from the official Android design guidelines: *Most alerts don't need titles. Usually the decision doesn't have a severe impact and can be summed up succinctly in a sentence or two.*

Comment: @JeffAxelrod - Are you saying that your answer does answer the question, or does not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Android Design guide on Alerts](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html#alerts) says:

> **Alerts**
>
> Alerts inform the user about a situation that requires their
>   confirmation or acknowledgement before proceeding. They differ
>   slightly in appearance based upon the severity and impact of the
>   message conveyed.
>
> **Alerts without title bars**
>
> Most alerts don't need titles. Usually the decision doesn't have a
>   severe impact and can be summed up succinctly in a sentence or two.
>   The content area should either ask a question (such as "Delete this
>   conversation?") or make a clear statement whose relationship to the
>   action buttons is obvious.
>
> [image: Dialog with no title]
>
> **Alerts with title bars**
>
> Keep the question or statement short: for example, "Erase USB
>   storage?" Avoid apologies. A user should be able to skip the content
>   completely and still have a clear idea of what choices are available
>   based on the title and the text of the action buttons.
>
> [image: Dialog with title]
>
> When crafting a confirmation dialog, make the title meaningful by
>   echoing the requested action.
>
> Don't:
>
> - Are you sure?
> - Don't
> - Warning!
>
> Do:
>
> - Erase USB storage?